# Phonegap - Android localhost using Flickr API

Tags: android, cordova, callback, flickr

I have created an app using Flickr API with Phonegap, installed my app on my android, then access it, but the app cant access `localhost`. I tried to config my Flickr API's Callback URL, but it doesnt work. What should I type in the Callback Url field? Here is an image of my Flickr API config.

[image]

Comment: On what port is your phonegap application running?

Comment: try giving your public ip. 192.168.x.x